# Specify x interval ticks between two dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas.core.series.Series `data` with its indices starting at '2000-01-03' and ending at '2013-12-31'. Example of the first 15 data points is follows

```
Date
2000-01-03    111.937502
2000-01-04    102.500003
2000-01-05    103.999997
2000-01-06     94.999998
2000-01-07     99.500001
2000-01-10     97.750001
2000-01-11     92.750000
2000-01-12     87.187503
2000-01-13     96.749998
2000-01-14    100.437499
2000-01-18    103.937499
2000-01-19    106.562499
2000-01-20    113.499994
2000-01-21    111.312501
2000-01-24    106.250002
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

When I plot the data in Jupyterlab

```
plt.plot(data, color='blue')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

The tick marks and their labels are just displayed in thick black blocks due to overlapping. How can I specify the intervals between the displayed tick marks as `x` days to prevent overlapping so that the x-axis could be readable? Thank you!

Comment: if you use the built-in plotting functions for pandas, it makes plotting with dates on the index much easier.  try `data.rename(pd.to_datetime).plot()`

Comment: There should be a minorticks_off() call on the plot object or something like that